# Create PostgreSQL table dynamically in Golang

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am using "database/sql" package in GO. I want to create a table with a dynamic name.

The only way I can think of is-

```
db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE`+table_name+`;`)
```

But it is not safe as there can be SQL injection.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't code in GO, but this would probably be safe for injection:

```
tx.Prepare(`do $$ begin execute format($f$create table %I()$f$,$1); end; $$;`)
```

and then

```
stmt.Exec(table_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use [QuoteIdentifier](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq?utm_source=godoc#QuoteIdentifier)

```
db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE TABLE %s", pq.QuoteIdentifier(table)))
```

Here are the lines from the documentation -

```
QuoteIdentifier quotes an "identifier" (e.g. a table or a column name) to be
used as part of an SQL statement.  
For example:

    tblname := "my_table"
    data := "my_data"
    quoted := pq.QuoteIdentifier(tblname)
    err := db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s VALUES ($1)", quoted), data)

Any double quotes in name will be escaped. 
The quoted identifier will be case sensitive when used in a query.  
If the input string contains a zero byte, the result will be truncated immediately before it.
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use placeholders like:

`db.Exec("CREATE TABLE $1", "table_name")`

[wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

> With most development platforms, parameterized statements that work with parameters can be used (sometimes called placeholders or bind variables) instead of embedding user input in the statement. A placeholder can only store a value of the given type and not an arbitrary SQL fragment. Hence the SQL injection would simply be treated as a strange (and probably invalid) parameter value.

Comment: From above statement **A placeholder can only store a value of the given type and not an arbitrary SQL fragment.**
table_name is not a value in given case.
It gives error-
`pq: syntax error at or near "$1".`

Answer (score -1):

Its just like @Vao Tsun said:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("CREATE TABLE $1")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stmt.Close()

result, err := stmt.Exec("DB_NAME_HERE")
```

Go through the original [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) and look at their example as well for clear understanding.

Comment: This too gives error- 
`pq: syntax error at or near "$1".`