# Creating PostgreSQL tables in Golang app with a dynamic name while using the golang-migrate library

Tags: postgresql, go, database-migration

I am new to the [golang-migrate/migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) library and started playing around with it.

I am interested in creating PostgreSql tables with dynamic names in my Golang app by using the migrate library and the `.up.sql` files with placeholders. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${my-variable-table-name}(

   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   email VARCHAR (300) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

I do know that I can create tables with dynamic names by using the [database/sql](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql) package with  the different `Exec()` methods as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809287/create-postgresql-table-dynamically-in-golang) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555836/is-it-possible-to-create-postgresql-databases-with-dynamic-names-with-the-help-o). However, I was wondering if this can be accomplished with the migrate library functionality only, without explicitly using the database/sql methods.

I searched a lot for any piece of information but could not find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly (see [this issue](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/issues/20)). However there is nothing to stop you using templates to build the migration files (either prior to calling ` m.Up()` or via a custom source e.g. a modified version of [file](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/master/source/file/file.go)). However this may mean that your migrations [are not easily reversible](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/master/MIGRATIONS.md#reversibility-of-migrations).